# Why does my prime number sieve include the number 49?

Tags: rust

I haven't been able to find the bug in my sieve implementation. My test shows the following error.

```
// Expected 
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
// Mine
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49]
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I realise it's the something to do with the final condition but I haven't been able to figure it out

```
/// Find all prime numbers less than `n`.
/// For example, `sieve(7)` should return `[2, 3, 5]`
pub fn sieve(n: u32) -> Vec<u32> {
    // Check assert and then populate vector
    assert!(n > 1, "Error n is less than 1");
    let mut is_prime: Vec<bool> = vec![true; (n-1) as usize];
    let sqrt: u32 = (n as f32).sqrt() as u32 + 1;
    for i in 2..sqrt {
        if is_prime[i as usize] == true {
            let mut k = i * i;
            loop {
                if k > n {
                    break;
                }
                is_prime[(k-2) as usize] = false;
                k += i;
                println!("i:{} k:{}", i, n);
            }
        }
    }
    let mut primes: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..is_prime.len() {
        if is_prime[i] == true {
            primes.push((i+2) as u32);
        }
    }
    println!("SQ{}", sqrt);
    println!("Vec {:?}", primes);
    primes
}
```

([Github](https://github.com/karbfg10k/Project/blob/master/Rust/cis198/hw01/src/problem3.rs))

Also is this a relatively fast implementation or am I making a big mistake (besides the prints, those are for debugging)?

Comment: What's up with all those explicit type annotations? You probably don't need any of them. It's more idiomatic in Rust to remove them. You should probably ask about your code on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) :)

Comment: Oh, I'm just starting with Rust and this is the first language I've used with type inference, so it's taking me a while to get out of my C habits :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that your "clever" trick to ignore the values `0` and `1` backfired and you didn't consistently shift your offsets up and down. Something like this appears to give the correct output:

```
fn sieve(n: u32) -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut is_prime = vec![true; (n-2) as usize];
    let sqrt = (n as f32).sqrt() as u32 + 1;
    for i in 2..sqrt {
        if is_prime[(i-2) as usize] {
            let mut k = i*i;
            loop {
                if k >= n {
                    break;
                }
                is_prime[(k-2) as usize] = false;
                k += i;
                println!("i:{} k:{}", i, n);
            }
        }
    }
    let mut primes = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..is_prime.len() {
        if is_prime[i] {
            primes.push((i+2) as u32);
        }
    }
    println!("SQ{}", sqrt);
    println!("Vec {:?}", primes);
    primes
}

fn main() {
    let a = sieve(50);
    assert_eq!(a, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]);
}
```